# Add ability to filter custom post type by custom fields?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using both the "Types" and the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugins for Wordpress. With "Types" I have created a custom post and when you click "add new" you create a new post by filling out the text areas and drop-downs that I created using "Advanced Custom Fields".

Currently, when I click on my post in the sidebar there is a filter to sort my subposts (sorry for the horrendous lack of proper terminology; I'm new to wordpress) by date added. I also want to be able to sort by some of the custom fields I have created in the dropdown box.

Also, there are two columns labelled "title" and "date". Is it possible to add a couple more?

Comment: Please add some code or show the example about the questions

Comment: There is no code to show. [Here is a screenshot of my dashboard](http://i.imgur.com/d1NtcMd.png). Projects is the custom post type in question. As you ca see there are already the columns called "Title" and "date". I want to be able to add more columns based on the custom fields i've created with "Advanced Custom Fields"

Comment: Yup you can sort the things based on custom fields, by doing some custome coding and 2nd you also add new columns in the listing by some `column_filter` checked the codex for details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Writing PHP

You can write some PHP as outlined by the developer of Advanced Custom Fields (Elliot Condon) in [this blog post](http://www.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields-admin-custom-columns/).

The following code taken from the post will display an [image](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) and a [true / false](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/) field in the admin screen:

```
function my_page_columns($columns)
{
    $columns = array(
        'cb'        => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'thumbnail' =>  'Thumbnail',
        'title'     => 'Title',
        'featured'  => 'Featured',
        'author'    =>  'Author',
        'date'      =>  'Date',
    );
    return $columns;
}

function my_custom_columns($column)
{
    global $post;
    if($column == 'thumbnail')
    {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_field('page_image', $post->ID), array(200,200) );
    }
    elseif($column == 'featured')
    {
        if(get_field('featured'))
        {
            echo 'Yes';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'No';
        }
    }
}

add_action("manage_pages_custom_column", "my_custom_columns");
add_filter("manage_edit-page_columns", "my_page_columns");
```

To be able to sort the true / false column you can use the following code as outlined in the post:

```
function my_column_register_sortable( $columns )
{
    $columns['featured'] = 'featured';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter("manage_edit-page_sortable_columns", "my_column_register_sortable" );
```

### Using a Plugin

Alternatively, without any PHP programming, you can do this using the [Admin Columns by Codepress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I actually came across that plugin before and ended up just using it.